# Why is this AWS S3 deny-user policy not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli, localstack

I'm learning AWS using LocalStack, currently learning about IAM policies, in the context of IAM users and S3 buckets, and I'm focusing on using the AWS CLI.

I attempted to create a policy to deny all S3 access to a specific user:

```
{
  "comment": "s3-deny-stanley.json",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/stanley" },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's stanley's profile:

```
$ aws --profile=admin_cred --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4593 iam get-user --user-name stanley
{
    "User": {
        "Path": "/",
        "UserName": "stanley",
        "UserId": "mnxybnqil4uugewvlq7x",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/stanley",
        "CreateDate": "2020-05-01T20:01:30.932000+00:00"
    }
}
```

I applied the policy like so:

```
$ aws --profile=admin_cred --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket my-bucket --policy file://s3-deny-stanley.json
$
```

I add a file to my bucket like so:

```
$ cat << EOF > foo.txt
> hello, world!
> EOF
$
$ aws --profile=admin_cred --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 cp ./foo.txt s3://my-bucket/foo.txt
upload: ./foo.txt to s3://my-bucket/foo.txt
```

Now I try to access the file as stanley, but against my hopes, he seems able to:

```
$ aws --profile=stanley --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 ls s3://my-bucket/
2020-05-01 14:33:03         14 foo.txt
$ aws --profile=stanley --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 cp s3://my-bucket/foo.txt ./foo2.txt
download: s3://my-bucket/foo.txt to ./foo2.txt
$
```

**Can someone please point out what's wrong in my above attempt to apply the s3-deny-stanley policy to my-bucket?**

(Apologies to stanley)

---

**Update:**
I checked that the policy is attached like so:

```
$ aws --profile=admin_cred --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket my-bucket
{
    "Policy": "{\n  \"comment\": \"s3-deny-stanley.json\",\n  \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\n  \"Statement\": [\n    {\n      \"Effect\": \"Deny\",\n      \"Action\": \"s3:*\",\n      \"Principal\": { \"AWS\": \"arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/stanley\" },\n      \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*\"\n    }\n  ]\n}\n\n"
}
```

---

**Update**:
Updated the policy to remove the "comment", as follows:

```
$ cat ./s3-deny-stanley.json
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/stanley" },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

From an abundance of caution, I deleted my original bucket, re-created it, applied the updated policy to it, and repeated the access attempt by stanley: the results were identical to those described originally.

Comment: Could you check whether the bucket policy is attached to `my-bucket`?

Comment: @jellycsc - done: updated the post

Comment: All look good to me. It seems like an existing localstack bug. https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/2238

Comment: @jellycsc - thank you; I'm not familiar with github; at the bottom of that page does whummer adding the "feature-missing" tag mean that it's been acknowledged as a bug? (For learning purposes, I'm mostly just interested in whether what I *tried* to do is correct - and I'm okay with this being a bug in LocalStack)

Comment: Let me quickly try it in aws and get back to you ◡̈ I wanna be 100% correct, especially not mislead you.

Comment: Could you try to remove the `comment` key and its value in the bucket policy json? I encountered an error when I save the bucket policy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212940/discussion-between-stonethrow-and-jellycsc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the behaviour that OP described on AWS. I gave stanley admin permission and got the following

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/key . --profile stanley
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

So I believe it's a localstack bug.